# RichTextBox color

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I wish color of text was e.g green when user inputs it into RichTextBox control. I use sth like:

```
 private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    RichTextBox richTextBox1 = sender as RichTextBox;
    richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
}
```

But it cause that first sign is in normal background, and starting from second sign whole eneterd text is blue:

pattern(upper case is colored):
eNTERED TEXT

Comment: You can probably set ForeColor directly on the RichTextBox.

Comment: Can you provide a pictorial view of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of TextChanged try it on OnKeyDown

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want to set:

```
richTextBox1.ForeColor = Color.AliceBlue
```

somewhere after your `InitializeComponent();` or via the `Background property` in the Designer.

Comment: but i want to change olny color of typed text by user. Text that was previously in control i would like to stay in default color.